# Panzoom can't work with list <ul> <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, zooming

I've been googling for several days..And i haven't found the answer.Would you guys help me?Thanks

I've tested jquery.panzoom.js and jquery mousewheel.js on an image..
It worked!
But it didn't work on my subway station map which used another js with "ul" and "li" inside..
Here's the code of my subway station map.. Would it be possible with panzoom.js?

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Subway Map</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.subwayMap-0.5.0.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.panzoom.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="panzoom">
     <div class="subway-map" data-columns="100" data-rows="20" data-cellSize="40" data-legendId="legend" data-textClass="text" data-gridNumbers="true" data-grid="false" data-lineWidth="8"> //create subway station
        <ul data-color="#ff00ff" data-label="Jakarta Kota - Gambir - Manggarai - Depok">          
            <li data-coords="2,6">\n\nJakarta\nKota</li> 
            <li data-coords="3.4,6">\n\nJayakarta</li> 
            <li data-coords="4.8,6">\n\nMangga\nBesar</li> 
            <li data-coords="6,6">\n\nSawah\nBesar</li> 
            <li data-coords="7.1,6">\n\nJuanda</li>
            <li data-coords="8.3,6" data-marker="interchange">\n\nGambir</li>
            <li data-coords="9.8,6">\n\nGondangdia</li>
            <li data-coords="11.2,6">\n\nCikini</li>
            <li data-coords="13.2,6" data-marker="interchange">\n\nManggarai</li>
            <li data-coords="14.5,6">\n\nTebet</li>
            <li data-coords="15.7,6">\n\nCawang</li>
            <li data-coords="17,6">\n\nDuren\nKalibata</li>
            <li data-coords="18.3,6">\n\nPasar\nMinggu\nBaru</li>
            <li data-coords="19.5,6">\n\nPasar\nMinggu</li>
            <li data-coords="20.7,6">\n\nTanjung\nBarat</li>
            <li data-coords="22,6">\n\nLenteng\nAgung</li>
            <li data-coords="23.4,6">\n\nUniv.\nPancasila</li>
            <li data-coords="24.7,6">\n\nPondok\nCina</li>
            <li data-coords="26,6">\n\nDepok\nBaru</li>
            <li data-coords="27.3,6">\n\nDepok</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="legend"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".subway-map").subwayMap({ debug: true });
    </script>
    <script>
        (function() {
          var $section = $('#focal');
          var $panzoom = $section.find('.panzoom').panzoom();
          $panzoom.parent().on('mousewheel.focal', function( e ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var delta = e.delta || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
            var zoomOut = delta ? delta < 0 : e.originalEvent.deltaY > 0;
            $panzoom.panzoom('zoom', zoomOut, {
              increment: 0.1,
              animate: false,
              focal: e
            });
          });
        })();
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It should be like this:
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9ovP.png)

But when i add `<script src="jquery.js"></script>`
Output become:
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Q0mX.png)

Comment: uuhhmm... "enter image description here" ?

Comment: when you click it,the image would be come out..

Comment: you couldn't name it though?